# Not able to Play video on Mobile?

Tags: android, video

I am using the Web-Service to play videos on Android Mobile.The same website I am using to play video in iPhone it is working fine.But in Samsung Android Mobile and some Motorola Adroid Mobiles video is not playing.
http://rompio.com/web_service/web.php?method=list_videos

Can anyone Please suggest me that why is is not getting played.Any useful suggestions that where I may be wrong .The Web-service is made perfectly fine.Also the Android code is perfectly fine as it is working in Experia Android Mobiles.

Comment: please show the logcat since it might contain media error logs.

Comment: on which android os you are trying to play?

Comment: Please post your code.